# Rotation of Dynamic Programming State and Using two layered state?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was studying this link for DP: http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/43256?mobile=true&locale=en 
The author is talking about layers of DP state. I am having hard time understanding the layers and rotation of DP state applied to example 'ConnectTheCities'. Can someone simplify the explanation of the solution provided there. I know that it's already much elaborated, but can you demonstrate the solution further and give more clarity for the example mentioned above. Any help would be appreciated a lot.
The problem statement for the example is here https://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=8185&rd=10786